# Creating a Navmesh in Aframe using aframe-inspector-plugin-recast

Tags: aframe

I'm using Don McCurdy's [A-Frame Inspector plugin](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-inspector-plugin-recast) to try to build a navmesh for some "stairs" that I've constructed essentially by sticking a bunch of box primitives together. You can see a demo at: 
http://webvr.decodingsteve.com/stair-nav/

For whatever reason though, I can't get the navmesh to generate, and the error message that's generated is completely opaque. I tried exporting my "stairs" as a single GLTF, (figuring maybe a single object would work better), but that didn't seem to have any effect either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just in case anyone else runs in to a similar problem, it turns out I was making a silly mistake. My scene only had the blocks I was using for stairs in it, and no flat surface, (like a plane), underneath to extend the navmesh on to. Adding a plane for the floor solved the issue and allowed the navmesh to be created.